# What were the most commonly used ships in the Rebel Alliance?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, the-rebel-alliance

In the original trilogy, X-wings are often seen as the face of the Rebel Alliance as they are one of the most numerous ships the Alliance have, but during the early rebellion (as seen in Star Wars Rebels) the Rebels use a number of different spacecraft (A-wings are often seen). **So what were the most numerous spacecraft that the Rebel Alliance used (with any possible figures/numbers)?**

Comment: Are you interested only in starfighters like the X/Y/A/B-wings? Or also in starships like the Nebulon-B Frigate or Mon Calamari Star Cruisers, or even the Rebel Transports?

Comment: There is a non-canon book from the 1990s: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Rebel_Alliance%E2%80%94Ships_of_the_Fleet#app_vehicles

Comment: They've got A-Wings in *Star Wars: Rebels* now? In Legends continuity, they weren't even out of production until the Battle of Endor!

Comment: @boolean - X-wings and other space fighters are the space equivalents of boats, not ships.  Therefore no class of space fighters could be the most common type of ships in the Rebel Alliance.

Comment: Not only do they have A-Wings in Rebels, they are by far the most used Rebel fighters in the show. X-Wings didn't even appear until Season 4 @Thunderforge

Comment: @Thunderforge weren't there A-Wings in The Force Unleashed 2? Also, R-21 Spearhead is basicly A-Wing v.09, and looks almost identical. The one at Endor were RZ-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the most commonly used ships in the Rebellion. The Rebellion used the CR90 Corvette, commonly called the Corellian Corvette, it was used as a blockade runner and is seen in the first few minutes of the first Star Wars movie released; the EF76 Nebulon-B class Escort Frigate (which the Empire also used, I believe), it is seen at the end of *The Empire Strikes Back* where Luke gets his prosthetic hand; the Y-Wing, which was developed during the Clone Wars and was used as a bomber, it appears in all three of the original trilogy movies, and it appears in the *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* television series as its early variant; the Mon Calamari star cruisers, such as the MC75 and MC80 cruisers, the MC80 appears first in *Return of the Jedi*, and the MC75 appears in *Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*; the X-Wing, even though you already said that, it appears in every Star Wars movie set during or after the era of the Galactic Civil War; the A-Wing, seen in *Return of the Jedi*; and the B-Wing, which appears in *Return of the Jedi*. If any of these are incorrect, or if I am missing any, then please, feel free to tell me. And if any of you can find a site that has the numbers of these ships used by the Rebellion, then tell me and I will give you credit.

Comment: Do you have example of their use in the Rebel Alliance?

Comment: this isn't quite an answer

Comment: Don't try to frighten us with your sorcerer's ways, Lord Vader. Your sad devotion to that ancient religion has not helped you conjure up the sources needed to support your answer. Maybe if you didn't choke all of your spies infiltrating the Rebellion, you would be able to cite their reports, or even better, provide actual counts of their appearances. I hear a Wookiee on the planet Pedia might be able to help you there. In the mean time, perhaps you should take a [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) of this battlestation and find out why it's the ultimate sci-fi power in the universe!

Comment: I already took the tour Thunderforge. lol. Also, I will give examples of their use, amflare.

Comment: still doesn't answer the question - you are just listing vehicles, not answering which ones were most used / numbers

Comment: I listed the ones MOST COMMONLY used. If I was just listing vehicles, then I would have listed many more, such as stolen Imperial craft, or Mark 2 Assault Frigates. I'll look up numbers later.

Comment: the question is "what were the most numerous spacecraft that the Rebel Alliance used" - there is nothing related to the numerous-ness of any of these craft. For example, we only see 1 Y-Wing in ESB. Looking at the context of the question, OP seems to be asking, in other words, as an example: "did the Rebels use more X-Wings or A-Wings?"

Comment: @NKCampbell he said most commonly used, not necessarily most numerous, although he did ask if we could give numbers then we should.