# Did any non-rebels regularly fly X-Wings?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In several places, including [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/183148/70477), it is mentioned that X-Wings are an iconic image of the Rebel Alliance.

Did any *unaffiliated* faction ever *regularly* fly X-Wings? By *unaffiliated*, I mean factions *other* than the following:

- Rebel Alliance
- New Republic
- Resistance

For example, did any pirate factions regularly fly X-Wings? Independent planetary militias? Any X-Wing flying Bounty Hunters? Did Jabba have a squadron of X-Wings tucked away somewhere?

Stolen X-Wings count if the stolen X-Wings were incorporated into the faction's star fleet and flown regularly. One or two stolen fighters used on special missions don't count. For example, if a downed Imperial TIE Fighter pilot stole a Rebel X-Wing in order to escape Hoth and make it back to his carrier so he could continue to fly TIE Fighters, that doesn't count. If he was allowed to keep it and fly it regularly as his assigned fighter until it was so worn out or damaged that Imperial mechanics couldn't repair it anymore, it can count.

For purposes of this question, "X-Wing" means T-65 and T-70 craft, as well as any obviously substantially similar craft. The [ARC-170](http://www.starwars.com/databank/arc-170-starfighter) doesn't count.

Comment: In Legends, only the Rebellion had X-Wings. That's because X-Wings were created by a team of Incom engineers who stole all prototypes and schematics and defected to the Rebellion. In new canon, they just sort of pop out of nowhere, and aside from Rebellion veterans, I can't think of anyone who flies an X-Wing.

Comment: Given the intentionally "distressed" appearance given to the rebel spacecraft, it stands to reason that they ought to have been old, well used military hardware.

Comment: Technically, Luke Skywalker "left" the Rebel Alliance and "joined" the Jedi Order, at which point he occasionally helps out if it doesn't interfere with other Jedi business. It seems he kept his X-Wing in *RotJ*. Whether this is a good answer or not probably depends on how you view Luke's relationship with the Rebellion/New Republic after he's a Jedi.

Comment: @Buzz Funnily enough, lots of of the rebel hardware (in Legends) is actually top-notch latest tech (the X-Wing, B-Wing, Mon Calamari cruisers...). Some look "clean" enough, others you could argue are a bit "dirty" because they don't get 100% maintenance and the limited technicians available need to prioritize heavily to make sure they *work*. Appearance is secondary.

Comment: Come to think of it, having a really noticeable shape to ships which scream "Screw you, authority" is a really bad strategy for an organisation which has to rely on spies and subterfuge, rather than military might...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Legends the X-Wing was originally designed for the Empire, Until Incom defected with the plans.

That is why it is primarily Rebellion (and offshoots) based and basically the Symbol of the Rebels.

As for non-Rebellion usage.

The Lightspeed Panthers (per *Star Wars: The Essential Guide to Warfare*) were a volunteer starfighter squadron that assisted the Rebellion but were not directly part of it and they flew X-Wings.

In *X-Wing: The Krytos Trap*, the pro-Imperial Palpatine Counterinsurgency Front has a squadron of X-Wings that were dressed up to resemble Rogue Squadron and used to try to impersonate them; unfortunately (for them) they ended up under the guns of Warlord Zsinj, who was happy to destroy them out of hand either way. It's not stated where the PCF obtained the X-Wings.

In *X-Wing: The Bacta War*, Ysanne Isard's fighter commander, Erisi Dlarit, tries to sell Isard on the merits of switching at least some of their squadrons from TIEs to X-Wings, which she considers to be superior fighters. She's overruled largely on the basis of Imperial nationalism; Isard thinks of the Alliance (including its fighters) as inferior and what she says, goes. Again the potential source isn't specified, but it may be worth noting that, lacking a factory for them, Isard's forces had been buying TIEs on the gray market.

Post-Galactic War X-Wing varients were used by many organizations in the galaxy that used them that were not exactly directly linked e.g. New Jedi Order and RASP.

Jedi Squadrons were formed mainly during the Yuuzhan Vong Crisis and seen in The Swarm War and through the Legacy of the Force Series and Fate of the Jedi series where they were still flying StealthX's.

RASP (Reconstruction Authority Space Patrol, aka Reconstruction Police) is a policing force that was setup by the Galactic Federation of Free Alliances post Yuuzhan Vong Crisis, mainly seen during The Swarm War and onward.

In canon, The Partisans (Saw Gerera's followers, as seen in *Rogue One* in the Jeddah scenes) used X-Wings also, and they were not included as part of the Rebel Alliance so that kind of fits.

It's also stated in canon that the X-Wing was is general rotation before becoming the almost exclusive fighter for the Rebellion.

Saponza from the game *Star Wars: Commander* was a mercenary that flew X-Wings but then joined the Rebellion. Not sure if that is pure canon.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! This is a good answer but would be better if you could link directly to your sources i.e. not through the wikia.

Comment: -1 As TheLethalCarrot said, primary sources are better than Wiki sources. See [this Harry Potter answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/172327/13217) for an example of when someone posted something they made up on a Wiki that everyone, including other sites, started to believe was true.

Comment: I'll go back through and provide better sources.

Comment: Cant really link the sources directly as they are books and movies mostly.

Comment: In that case, an excerpt with the book name and page number is fine

Comment: @NicholasTsaoucis- what does RASP stand for? I don't recall seeing it elsewhere.

Comment: The series is called [*X-Wing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_X-wing_%28book_series%29). So it's *X-Wing: The Bacta War* and *X-Wing: The Krytos Trap*. The series notably switched squadrons and authors in the 5th book (and started going every which way from the 8th onward).

Comment: @Nu'Daq edited for clarity

Comment: The events in 'Leia: Princess of Alderaan' makes it seem like the Partisans were more directly linked with the early rebellion than this answer may imply.

Comment: @DoritoStyle The events of Star Wars: Rebels and Rogue One tell us that whilst they were a part of the early rebellion, they were deemed too extreme and were effectively cut off from the main Rebellion. The Rebel Alliance itself, before it became more organised, was effectively all just resistance cells all over the place acting on their own initiative.

Comment: 'Early rebellion' is the key phrase there. That could possibly disqualify them from OP's category since they would have had access to the same  supplies as the rebellion to an extent, and so their use of X-wings isn't particularly novel IMO.

Again, 'Leia' offers insight into when the Rebel Armada was organized, but it's still not clear at which point Saw was excluded from those resources.

Comment: Corran Horn, one of the main characters of the X-Wing series, regularly piloted an X-Wing as part of his duties as a Corellian Security Force (CorSec) officer. In "Legends", Correllia only joined the New Republic in 12 ABY, while Horn joined Rogue Squadron in 6 ABY. CorSec was thus a non-republic and non-rebellion entity that regularly used X-Wings as part of their fleet.

Comment: @Dungarth That was an answer that was included further down, so I did not add it to the answer here. Do you think I should add it to keep them together?

Comment: @NicholasTsaoucis - Yeah, didn't read all the answers before adding that comment, sorry!

Answer (score 12):

This is pure Legends, but in the Han Solo Trilogy, Han was captured and sent to Kessel to work the mines. When he was being attacked, a few squads of ships, including a squad entirely of X-Wings, attacked the *Falcon*.

Comment: Good find! Do you have a quote from the book to back it up?

Comment: I own the book. I'll find you that quote ASAP.

Comment: Wasnt that in The Jedi Academy: Jedi Search?

Comment: Nicholas Tsaoucis yes, I went home and checked. It is actually from Jedi Search.

Comment: That was one of my first series of star wars books I owned, I remember the cover art really well which is why it came to me. Also setup one of my favorite characters from legends, Kyp Durren.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but not in any great numbers. For instance, Corran Horn, who was originally with the Corellian Security Force, flew a captured X-Wing on missions with Cor Sec before joining the Rebellion/New Republic.

This was mentioned in passing during dialogue during the Rogue Squadron series.

> On what I thought would be my last assignment I drew an X-wing from the pool of craft we'd captured and converted to CorSec use.

This is from the first book of that series [Rogue Squadron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_Squadron_(novel)).